# Rails 4.1 scope with includes failed with unknown column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, scope

After upgrading rails 4.0 to 4.1, Following code is breaking saying

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'user_groups.id' in 'where clause

scope :check_access, lambda {|user| includes(:user_groups).where('restrict_access is false or user_groups.id in (?)', user.get_user_group_ids) if user}
```

What would be the correct syntax to use above with rails 4.1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`includes` no longer guarantees a join between your source table and the included relationship. Rails may decide to preload the associated information using either a join or through two separate queries.

In addition to `includes`, you should add a `references(:user_groups)` clause, which will give ActiveRecord enough information to know what your intentions are.

```
scope :check_access, lambda { |user| 
  includes(:user_groups).references(:user_groups).where('restrict_access is false or user_groups.id in (?)', user.get_user_group_ids) if user
}
```

As a side note, your construction will return either an ActiveRecord relation if user record exists, or `nil` if it doesn't. You might be better off using the `.none` method to return an empty collection instead:

```
scope :check_access, lambda { |user|
  if user
    includes(:user_groups)
      .references(:user_groups)
      .where('restrict_access is false or user_groups.id in (?)', user.get_user_group_ids)
  else
    none
  end
}
```

That way, `check_access` will *always* return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` collection object, so you can safely chain it with other scopes if need be.

Comment: Everyone is different but on my team if a scope gets this big we will turn it into a class method instead.

Comment: Mine too! I didn't want to change the `scope` definition too far here, though, to keep the suggested code as closed as possible to the original so that SO users who may be new to Rails have a better chance of following along.

Comment: I think you handled it perfectly by not going too far away from the OP's question. I just thought I'd throw in my suggestion. Your's should be the selected answer.